# turbo c++ graphics.h program on android studio NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, bgi

I have a got a c++ program having graphics.h
can i use this program to make an android app in android studio.
As i know c++ programs can run using android NDK,but it shows graphics.h not found.

Comment: No, you're not going to be able to do that.

Comment: You'll need to get yourself a compiler that's not several decades out of date and you need to forget about graphics.h .

Answer (score 3):

In android you can only draw on screen using Java SDK APIs or C++ OpenGL ES/Vulkan APIs that are bundled in NDK.

So you won't be able to use `graphics.h`